# I tried to add compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0' in app.gradle

Tags: android, google-maps, gradle, compilation, android-glide

I tried to add compile

App **bulid.gradle**

```
compile  'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

when I try to run the app, it gives me the error

> NoClassDefFound erroe

I have the following dependencies in gradle

```
compile 'commons-io:commons-io:+'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.10'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.5.0'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.+'
```

Error is as follows:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION:                                                                               
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$string
at com.google.android.gms.measurement.zza.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.measurement.zza.zzaR(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzn.zziJ(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzz.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzw.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzaa.zzDj(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzw.zzaT(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: why `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'`?

Comment: I need to have notification and other play services in my app

Comment: why do you `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'` separately? its already in the play-services lib

Comment: Ok..that I agree..but still i am getting the error

Comment: rebuilding works fine..but on running the app only I am getting the error..

Comment: where do you get that error

Comment: error is coming by the time the app is opened.."unfortunately stopped"

Comment: Add the Logcat to the question then.

Comment: posted the error in question. 
the error occurs only after adding compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0' in gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update google play services and google repository in your android SDK. If it is still not fixed, Have you already add on the last line in your app build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```